# Handling isset and select box in php html and for loop

Tags: php, html, post, if-statement, for-loop

Here is my code. This needs some optimization if you think the below code is bad and someone can really help me

1. I'm using two if condition and two else condition. Is there anyway this can be fine-tuned.
2. In the search box i need to retain the previous selected book name. i.e when the submit button is clicked the select box should display the result with the
   selected item in the select box. for ex: if in dropdown if i select "book1" and click the submit button, the result should be displayed along with the "book1" as default inside the select box. in my case, the search box is getting reset on each submit click.

My Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $get_project_id = $_POST['project_name'];
    if($get_project_id == 1){
        ..display all the books(mysql query)..
    }else{
        ..display the particular  book(mysql query)..
    }
}else{
    ..if the search button is not clicked then display all the books(mysql query)..
}
?>
<form method="post" name="book_list">
    <select name="book_list" id="book_list">
        <option value="1">All Books</option>
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_books)){?>
        <option value="<?php  echo $row['Project_Auto_Id'];?>">
            <?php  echo $row['Book_Id']. " - ".$row['Book_Name'] ;?>
        </option>
    <?php  }?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Search"/> 
</form>
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Than,ks
Kimz

Comment: Do the statements "..display all the books(mysql query).." and "..if the search button is not clicked then display all the books(mysql query).." result in the same list of books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by checking the condition inside while loop. Checking the value of option and the post value are same or not as shown in the below code.

```
   <form method="post" name="book_list">
        <select name="book_list" id="book_list">
            <option value="1">All Books</option>
        <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_books)){?>
            <option <?php if(isset($_POST['book_list']) && ($_POST['book_list'] == $row['Project_Auto_Id'])) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php  echo $row['Project_Auto_Id'];?>">
                <?php  echo $row['Book_Id']. " - ".$row['Book_Name'] ;?>
            </option>
        <?php  }?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Search"/> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Updated the code, so that it wont show error when the select box is not selected (that is `$_POST['book_list']` is not set)

Comment: You might want to try that, it wont work. For starters `checked` is for radio buttons and checkboxes, not selects. You're using two `$$` instead of ampersands and you don't close your PHP tag.

Comment: sorry. My mistake. I typed checked instead of selected when typed fast. :P

Answer (score 1):

1. Not sure if there is any better way to do the two `if... else` statements but even if there is there's nothing wrong with the way you've done it, just a different way.
2. With regards to having the option selected after submitting you need to change your output of the options to this:

   ```
   <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_books)){?>
       <option value="<?php  echo $row['Project_Auto_Id'];?>"<?php if(isset($_POST['book_list']) && $_POST['book_list'] == $row['Project_Auto_Id']) echo ' selected'; ?>>
           <?php  echo $row['Book_Id']. " - ".$row['Book_Name'] ;?>
       </option>
   <?php  }?>
   ```